# Add Rowfilter condition for DateTime Year only check

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

I am trying to use a DataView.RowFilter in order to filter all entries that do not belong in a specified year.  My code is as follows:

```
bigDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "year(date_posted)=2011";
```

This however, does not work.  I have read that I can specify DateTimes using a format like "#mm/dd/yyyy#".

I'd prefer if I could check only the year, as users can specify a year, or no year, or month, or day, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Valid [expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cabd21yw%28vs.71%29.aspx) for DateTime.

You can do something like

```
"date_posted > #1/1/2011# AND  date_posted <  #12/31/2011#"
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like this is the only type of solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying this is a good way to do it, but a way you *can* do it is this:

```
bigDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CONVERT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(date_posted, 'System.String'), 5, 4), 'System.Int32')=2012";
```

That's converting the `date_posted` column to a string, extracting the four-digit date, converting that to an integer, and comparing that for equality to `2012`.  The `CONVERT` and `SUBSTRING` functions are documented in the [`DataColumn.Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx).

The documentation doesn't say, but I imagine that `CONVERT(date_posted, 'System.String')` uses the short date pattern for your current culture, so in my case (en-US) the year was at character offsets 5-8.  [Anurag Ranjhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201965/150605) is certainly better given how verbose this is and its reliance on parsing formatted strings, but this is another way to do it and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the document has the column name "year" and the field in that column is a text or datetime. If it is datetime, you need to be specific and probably include the date, time, etc. If it is text it should be defaultview.rowfilter = "year = 2011".

Comment: The column name is date_posted, and it is a DateTime object.  Is there no way to extract the year out of the DateTime object?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can format the datetime to a year only using datetime.tostring() (with all the format texts). Read upon datetime formatting on the web. It should get it done using formatting. Datetime is tricky and user needs to be very specific. Else filter it manually like datetime.year and loop through it and get it yourself.